# Não consigo mudar a cor do botão (xml) no Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, button

Não consigo mudar a cor do botão no Android Studio. Sempre que crio um botão pelo XML ele assume a cor primaria que é setada em *Themes.xlm* e quando vou setar uma cor, o código não da erro mas o botão não muda de cor. Não achei em nenhum lugar, como devo proceder?

[image: Codigo XML setando a cor branca]

[image: Botão sem mudar de cor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Luiz Felipe, beleza?

Então, existem algumas formas de trocar a cor de botão, e se ele está pegando a cor do seu tema, provavelmente é a `colorAccent`.

Algumas das formas são:


**[Criar um novo style e atribuir ao botão (recomendada para melhor padronização)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954610/14024291):**

```
 <style name="Button.White" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Que no botão ficaria:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Button.White"
    />
```

**Você pode também tentar o [backgroundTint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:backgroundTint) para APIs >= 21:**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    />
```

Dê uma procurada também em como setar estes valores programaticamente.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Fala Lucas! Tentei o Style e não funcionou, mas o backgroundTint deu certo! Talvez seja por conta da API mesmo. Muito obrigado pela força. Um abraço!

Answer (score -2):

Saudações Luiz

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/Button"

android:text="Button"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="30sp"

android:layout_width="270dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/cor_do_button"
android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
android:shadowDx="0"
android:shadowDy="0"
android:shadowRadius="5"
/>
```

com o Butão criado
vao a pasta:
app/rest/drawable
crie uma cor_do_button clicando com mouse no lado direito(right click) vai aperecer new passe o mouse e vam apara "Drawable resource file"
crie com nome cor_do_button(xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:radius="14dp"
/>
<solid
android:color="#11114F"
/>
<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"
/>
<size
android:width="270dp"
android:height="60dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#878787"
/>
</shape>
```

qualquer duivda bate ai

Comment: Fala Jorge, muito obrigado pela força! Mas não mudou ainda!! Esse segundo código, que seta o botão, mudou o layout, ele deixou de ficar quadrado e ao lado do código XML no AS apareceu a cor azul que foi passada, mas na View mesmo, ele continua com a cor do tema(rosa)... Estou achando que é algum problema no meu AS ou nos projetos que estou criando... De qualquer maneira muito obrigado pela Ajuda!!

Comment: Olha sugiro que emigre para flutter ou react native e muito mais pratico